# How to keep response body on non-200 responses in Oracle UTL_HTTP?

Tags: oracle, http

I find that if I call `UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE` and get an error response (500 in this case), when I call `UTL_HTTP.READ_TEXT` it fails with `ORA-29261: bad argument`. How can I see the response body when there is an error?

Comment: turned out I just had to call `UTL_HTTP.set_response_error_check(false);`

Comment: Yep, I see the same call earlier in my package ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution ended up being to call

```
UTL_HTTP.set_response_error_check(false);
```

before making the request.

Answer (score 2):

What I've done in the past is to read through the headers and then do a read_line to get the individual response lines:

```
v_resp := utl_http.get_response (v_req);

v_status := v_resp.status_code;

FOR i IN 1..UTL_HTTP.GET_HEADER_COUNT(v_resp) LOOP
  utl_http.get_header(v_resp, i, v_name, v_value);
  dbms_output.put_line(v_name || ': ' || v_value);
END LOOP;

BEGIN
  utl_http.read_line(v_resp, v_value, TRUE);
  v_response := v_value;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_value);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    NULL;  -- handle exception here
END;
```