# calling a fixer API in plsql to get currency rate

Tags: web-services, plsql, fixer.io

I have a Fixer.io API to get Current currency rate , i want to get the currency rate in PLSQL. Before this i have tried in Php to get the rate . Now i want to call the same in PLSQL to get the current rate. What i have tried in plsql

```
declare 
 req   UTL_HTTP.REQ;
BEGIN
 req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST('http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=access_key');
 UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(req, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
 UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(req);

 dbms_output.put_line('hitting');

EXCEPTION
 WHEN UTL_HTTP.END_OF_BODY THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('exception');
END;
```

its not working and giving the below error

`GET_RESPONSE' is not a procedure or is undefined`

need Suggestion regarding according to requirements

Comment: Not sure but you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998566/how-to-keep-response-body-on-non-200-responses-in-oracle-utl-http

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that GET_RESPONSE is a function not a procedure, therefor 
 you need to return it back into a variable see https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_http.htm#ARPLS70993 for a more detailed description.

You will need to declare a response variable

```
resp  UTL_HTTP.RESP;
```

then your call to get response would look like

```
resp := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(req);
```